# How to debug fourth-order Runge-Kutta for a differential equation in Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I have been trying to solve this differential equation using Runge Kutta method on Python. I haven't been able to get the right result with the code I wrote. What could be wrong here? The equation is:

```latex
$$ \frac{du_l}{dx} = u,
   \frac{du}{dx}   = (V-w^2)u_l $$
```

The code that I wrote is: (Here, *Rd* is the second derivative, *x0* and *x1* are the boundary *x* coordinate values, *V* is a dictionary, *V[l]*=some matrix (V varies with l), *ul0* is the initial value for the solution, *n* is a variable which decides the initial value of the first derivative(1,-1). h is the step size, *l* is some range over which I need to calculate values). [The indentation here is not right, but it works fine on Python].

```python
def Rd(ul,V):
    return (V-w**2)*ul

def sol(Rd,x0,x1,V,ul0,n,h,l):   
    ulR_final={}
    n1=int((x1-x0)/h)  
    xVs1=xV(x0,x1,V,h,l)  
    xVs2=xV(x0,x1,V,h/2,l)

    for j in range(1,l,1):
        xV1=xVs1[j]
        xV2=xVs2[j]
        #x1data=pd.DataFrame(xV1[:,0])
        #x2data=pd.DataFrame(xV2[:,0])
        #data=pd.concat([x1data,x2data],axis=1)
        #print(data.head(50))
        #print(len(xV1),len(xV2))
        x_values=xV1[:,0] 
        ul_values=[ul0]
        u0=math.sqrt(abs(w**2-xV1[0,1]))*ul0*1j*n
        u_values=[u0]
        ulR_values=np.zeros((n1,4), dtype=complex) 
        for i in range(n1-1):
            x=xV1[i,0]
            V=xV1[i,1]
            x1=xV1[i+1,0]
            V_1=xV1[i+1,1] 
            x2=xV2[(2*i)+1,0]
            V_2=xV2[(2*i)+1,1]

            #print(x,'x+h/2',x2,x+(h/2),'x+h',x1,x+h)
            ul=ul_values[-1]
            u=u_values[-1]

            k1ul=h*u
            k2ul=h*(u+(k1ul/2))
            k3ul=h*(u+(k2ul/2))
            k4ul=h*(u+(k3ul/2))

            k1u=h*Rd(ul,V)
            k2u=h*Rd(ul+(k1u/2),V_2)
            k3u=h*Rd(ul+(k2u/2),V_2)
            k4u=h*Rd(ul+(k3u),V_1)

            ul_new=ul+((k1ul+(2*k2ul)+(2*k3ul)+k4ul)/6)
            u_new=u+((k1u+(2*k2u)+(2*k3u)+k4u)/6)

            ul_values.append(ul_new)
            u_values.append(u_new)

            ulR_values[i,0]=x
            ulR_values[i,1]=np.round(ul_new,decimals=5) 
            ulR_values[i,2]=np.round(u_new,decimals=5)  
            ulR_values[i,3]=j
            

        ulR_final[j]=ulR_values[:-1]
        
    return ulR_final
```

Comment: Less of an answer but perhaps some general tips:  
-I'd recommend strongly to look at the numpy library and their arrays. Such an array basically acts as a vector. It also comes with other nice functions such as linspace and arange. A lot of your code generates computational overhead.  
-Try to breakdown the steps in smaller functions which you can separately debug. Like, make a function that takes the vector as an input and gives you the vector at $t + \Delta t$ as an output via RK. That will help a lot, also with readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think you implemented the RK procedure wrongly:

- First, you should do each step of RK together on both variables instead of only considering one variable at a time. So in your code, you want to compute in pairs (k1ul, k1u) -> (k2ul, k2u). Because your system is coupled, the result of the pair (k1ul, k1u) you need to compute (k2ul, k2u). Try to take look at the RK scheme again, you can't apply it to the variables separately.
- The invidual steps in your RK computation are wrong. Take your second line for instance: k2ul = h * (u + k1ul/2). This is not what the differential equation says. k1ul is the derivative of ul, not of u. So the addition u + k1ul/2 is like writing $u + .5 \cdot \frac{du_l}{dx}$, which is wrong.

Comment: Off-topic questions should not be answered.

Comment: I see, I admit that the question is off-topic. However, saying that they should not be answered is quite negative. Is there even a rule that forbids answering off-topic questions? In the best case both can be transferred to https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see I made very basic conceptual mistakes. I was able to correct my code. Also thanks for the advice, it does take unnecessary time to compute and obtain results, so I will do as you advised. Sorry for the off topic question, its my first time asking a question.